# Assign HTML form inputs to variables in Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

How do I store HTML form inputs inside a variables in Node JS. Where am I going wrong?
Here is my HTML form

```
<form action="localhost:8080/api/aa" method="post">
    <input id="host"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Host Name" > <br/>
    <input id="port" type="text" placeholder="Enter Port" ><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And my node app where I need my form inputs assigned to the variables
test.js**strong text**

```
var port        = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
var router      = express.Router();

var hostname    ='';
var port2       ='';
var url         ='';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', router);

router.post('/aa', function(req, res){ 
    hostname = req.body.hostname;
    port2 = req.body.port2;
    console.log(res);
    console.log(hostname);
    console.log(port2);   
});
url ="mongodb://"+hostname+":"+port2;
console.log(url); 

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at port ' + port);
console.log(url);
```

Not sure if my form inputs are being correctly handled. The submission of form doesn't reflect the values entered in form on to the Node JS variables

Answer (score 1):

Where are `hostname` and `port2` defined in the HTML form? The keys should be defined by the `name` attribute:

```html
<form action="localhost:8080/api/aa" method="post">
    <input id="host" name="hostname"  type="text" placeholder="Enter Host Name" > <br/>
    <input id="port" name="port2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Port" ><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Be aware that your Node global variables **will be shared by all your users**.

Comment: It is still not taking the input values.

Comment: Any log? Can your log `req.body`?

Comment: console.log(req.body) returns nothing. Could you check if the endpoints are correct?

Comment: Can you check the inspector o your browser to check if the request is being sent correctly? If so, any status code of the response?

Comment: Status says it was cancelled

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue but we will need more info. Console errors?

Comment: don't think it has anything to do with cors error since I'm using app.use(cors()) and console is black and not returning my logs

Comment: hey, I gave the complete endpoint and  it is working now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Nice to hear! :)